# Why is this action not being hit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For some reason, I cannot get an action to be hit. I am using `RedirectToAction` to pass the flow from one action to another, but it does not enter that function.

Here is the first action:

```
Public Function AddToCart(productId As Integer, returnUrl As String) As RedirectToRouteResult
    Dim product As Product = Me.Repository.Products _
        .FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = productId)

    If Not IsNothing(product) Then
        Me.Cart.AddItem(product, 1)
    End If

    Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})

End Function
```

That action gets hit (verified by a breakpoint). The subsequent action (Index) called via `Return RedirectToAction("List", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})` never gets hit (also verified by a breakpoint.

This is the Index action function:

```
Public Function Index(returnUrl As String) As ViewResult
    Dim cartIndexViewModel As New CartIndexViewModel() With { _
        .Cart = Me.Cart, _
        .ReturnUrl = returnUrl _
    }
    Return View(cartIndexViewModel)
End Function
```

I am not sure it is relevant, but it might be worth to note that I created a View for the Index action, but later deleted and recreated it.

As a sanity check I then created another Action named **List** that is identical to the **Index** action, and this action does get hit (again, verified by a breakpoint)

This is the code of my controller in its entirety:

```
Imports SportsStore.Domain

Namespace SportsStore.WebUI
    Public Class CartController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

#Region "Properties"

Public Property Cart As Cart
    Get
        If IsNothing(Session("Cart")) Then
            Session("Cart") = New Cart()
        End If
        Return CType(Session("Cart"), Cart)
    End Get
    Set(value As Cart)
        Session("Cart") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Repository As IProductRepository
Private Property Repository() As IProductRepository
    Get
        Return _Repository
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IProductRepository)
        _Repository = value
    End Set
End Property

#End Region 'Properties

#Region "Constructors"

    Public Sub New(repository As IProductRepository)
        Me.Repository = repository
    End Sub

#End Region 'Constructors

#Region "Actions"
        '
        ' GET: /Cart

    Public Function AddToCart(productId As Integer, returnUrl As String) As RedirectToRouteResult
        Dim product As Product = Me.Repository.Products _
            .FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = productId)

        If Not IsNothing(product) Then
            Me.Cart.AddItem(product, 1)
        End If

'DOES NOT WORK
        'Return RedirectToAction("List", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})
'WORKS
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})

    End Function

    Public Function RemoveFromCart(productId As Integer, returnUrl As String) As RedirectToRouteResult
        Dim product As Product = Me.Repository.Products _
            .FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = productId)

        If Not IsNothing(product) Then
            Me.Cart.RemoveLine(product)
        End If

        Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})

    End Function

    Public Function List(returnUrl As String) As ViewResult
        Dim cartIndexViewModel As New CartIndexViewModel() With { _
            .Cart = Me.Cart, _
            .ReturnUrl = returnUrl _
        }
        Return View(cartIndexViewModel)
    End Function

    Public Function Index(returnUrl As String) As ViewResult
        Dim cartIndexViewModel As New CartIndexViewModel() With { _
            .Cart = Me.Cart, _
            .ReturnUrl = returnUrl _
        }
        Return View(cartIndexViewModel)
    End Function

#End Region 'Actions

    End Class
End Namespace
```

And here is the structure of the project:

[image: Project Structure]

What am I missing?

Comment: You might have a typo in this question ... your code block says `Return RedirectToAction("Index" ...` but your inline code says `Return RedirectToAction("List" ...`.

Comment: @ScottRippey: Fixed in answer

Comment: Now that you've changed the question, I do not see any problem.  You redirect to "List", and then "List" gets hit, and "Index" doesn't get hit.  What's the problem?

Comment: @ScottRippey: My apologies. I've cleaned up the Action calls. Any idea why **Index** is not being hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code it appears you are redirecting to the Index action rather than the List action, from AddToCart().

```
Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.returnUrl = returnUrl})
```

Comment: I **want** the code to redirect to Index but it does not get there. What you see is my sanity check to another method I created called List.